# Requiring a model file in sidekiq worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I have a model file 'abc.rb' inside model directory.

```
class Abc
  class << self
     //codes
   end
end
```

There are certain methods in the `abc.rb` file that I want to call to in my `workers/bulk_uploader.rb` file. I got an error while calling it like `Abc.some_method`.

I also required the file `require '../models/abc.rb'` but i got an error in sidekiq console

> No such file to load -- ../models/abc (LoadError)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a blunder mistake. I mistyped the method name.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons why you got an error when calling `Abc.some_method` is it wasn't defined on `self.`.

```
class Abc 
  def self.some_method
    puts "Meow"
  end

  def some_other_method
    puts "Woof"
  end
end

Abc.some_method           # => Meow
Abc.some_other_method     # => undefined method `some_other_method' for Abc:Class
Abc.new.some_other_method # => Woof
```

You shouldn't have to require any model files.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices